# Disk usage as a percentage for individual disks in KDE

Tags: linux, storage, kde, resource-usage, system-monitoring

I would like to get the throughput percentage used on a per-storage basis in KDE. Much like how it is done in Windows.

I have managed to get the read and write speeds of all the storage combined but have not been able to separate them on a per-storage basis nor get the speeds to show up as a percentage of the maximum throughput. I am only able to separate them by per-partition.

[image]

Here is how it looks on Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are heaps of commands on Linux for displaying disk activities.
Just to mention some of them: iostat, iotop, dstat,atop and ioping.
For seeing them in action see the article
[5 Tools for Monitoring Disk Activity in Linux](https://www.opsdash.com/blog/disk-monitoring-linux.html).

As most of these tools were meant to be used in the console, perhaps
the following look most like your Windows tool:

[**Drive I/O System Monitor Plasmoid**](https://store.kde.org/p/1127589/)
(requires [Plasma](https://kde.org/plasma-desktop/))

[image]

[**Disk I/O Activity and Temperatures**](https://store.kde.org/p/1104097/)
(requires [SuperKaramba](http://netdragon.sourceforge.net/ssuperkaramba.html)

[image]

(Note: I don't know how the above two tools relate to your working
environment.)